# Proof that if the principal divisor of a function $ f $ on a nonsingular irreducible variety is non-negative, then $ f $ is regular.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In his "Basic Algebraic Geometry I", Shafarevich proves that for a nonsingular irreducible variety, if $ \operatorname{div}f \geq 0 $ then $ f $ is regular on $ X. $

He begins

> Let $ x \in X $ be a point at which $ f $ is not regular. Then $ f = g/h $ with $ g,h \in \mathcal{O}_{x} $ but $ g/h \notin \mathcal{O}_{x}. $ It follows from the fact that $ \mathcal{O}_{x} $ is a UFD that we can choose $ g $ and $ h $ with common factors. Let $ \pi $ be the prime element of $ \mathcal{O}_{x} $ that divides $ h $ but not $ g. $ In some affine neighbourhood $ U $ of $ x, $ the variety $ V(\pi) $ is irreducible and of codimension $ 1. $ Write $ C $ for its closure in $ X. $

I'm fine with all this. My difficulty is with the following statement:

> Then obviously $ v_C(f) < 0. $ This proves that $ \operatorname{div}f \geq 0 \Longrightarrow f $ regular.

I'm not sure why $ v_C(f) < 0. $ If $ h = m \cdot \pi, $ then $$ v_C(f) = v_C(g)-v_C(h) = v_C(g) -v_C(m)-v_C(\pi). $$

What am I missing?

Comment: Note $v_C(g) = 0$ because $\pi$ does not divide $g$.

Comment: If you write \text{div} rather than \operatorname{div} in either MathJax or LaTeX, then you may see something like $3\text{div}(f)$ rather than $3\operatorname{div}(f),$ the latter being standard usage. This does not just mean there's some space to the left and right of "div" when \operatorname{} is used; rather with \operatorname{} the spacing depends on the context. Thus with \operatorname{div}f you see $\operatorname{div}f$ whereas with \text{div}f you see $\text{div}f.$ Standard usage is \operatorname{div} rather than \text{div}. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @MichaelHardy